# how to unit test an Activity using google-api-client

Tags: android, unit-testing, google-api-client

I'm developing an Android app and I'm wondering how to unit test an *Activity* or a *Service* using *GoogleApiClient*.

For instance, how to test an *Activity* or *Service* in the case *GooglePlayService* is available and in the case it is unavailable ? I was thinking about using *Mockito* but since *GoogleApiClient* is instantiated from inside the *Activity*, there is no way to mock it (AFAIK).

```
public class MyService extends Service {
...
private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
...
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    ...
    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this) ... .build();
    ...
}
...
private void doSomething() {
    if(googleApiClient.isConnected) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Further more, I've read that mocking a third party library shouldn’t be done because my test suite won't fail if the library is updated but how can I do otherwise ?

PS: I'm sure this question has been asked before but I couldn't find the good keywords :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need mocking. But...

> (...) since GoogleApiClient is instantiated from inside the Activity

This, as you already observed, defeats the purpose of mocking and is a potential improvement point. Instantiating external services should happen either via [factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) (which can then be mocked very easily) or via [dependency injection container](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) and passed to class as such (which again can be mocked easily).

> Further more, I've read that mocking a third party library shouldn’t be done because my test suite won't fail if the library is updated but how can I do otherwise ?

This is rather strange claim. You will (at least should) have integration tests doing more broad range of component testing where actual 3rd party libraries will be used. In unit test you *mock* dependencies (any dependencies) in order to test in isolation and focus on **unit**.

Comment: Thanks to your response, I've discovered _Dagger_ (a DI framework) which fits perfectly my needs.

Comment: @AntoineFontaine did you actually inject `GoogleApiClient` using dagger? How did you do it? I'm stuck on how to register the callbacks...

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't remember how I've done it, it was a little personal project to learn Android and I've lost the sources